# Transforming a 2D image into 3D

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I want to transform a 2D colour (RGB from OpenCV) image into a 3D image using Python (using OpenCV, PIL, SKImage, etc.). Many of the examples I've found (such as https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html#perspective-transformation) show you how to take a 2D image that represents a 3D object and convert to a 2D view (e.g. top down). I want to do the opposite, I have a top-down image and want to display it with different angles applied to rotation around the image centre and the X-axis (so it looks like I'm viewing the image on the table from a sitting position).
How can I do this? Specifically how do I construct the rotation and skew matrices?

I've found the following code, but it doesn't quite do what I want. It only works with grayscale images too, mine are currently in colour.

Also this code achieves a somewhat similar effect but it doesn't allow me to specify the angle of rotation, so in effect I have to play about with values to reflect what I think the rotated image should look like. https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/examples/star_worms.html

```
# from skimage import transform
from skimage.transform import warp, ProjectiveTransform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('.top-down-image.jpeg')

theta = np.deg2rad(20)
tx = 0
ty = 0

S, C = np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)

# Rotation matrix, angle theta, translation tx, ty
H = np.array([[C, -S, tx],
              [S,  C, ty],
              [0,  0, 1]])

# Translation matrix to shift the image center to the origin
r, c = img.shape
T = np.array([[1, 0, -c / 2.],
               [0, 1, -r / 2.],
              [0, 0, 1]])

# Skew, for perspective
S = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
              [0, 1.3, 0],
              [0, 1e-3, 1]])

trans = ProjectiveTransform(T)
img_rot = warp(img, H)
img_rot_center_skew = warp(img, S.dot(np.linalg.inv(T).dot(H).dot(T)))

for i in [img, img_rot, img_rot_center_skew]:
    f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20))
    ax.imshow(i, cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='nearest')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Hey mstreffo, I'm kind of having the same intention as yours and currently stuck. Have you found a solution / hint that you could share with us ? Highly appreciated

Comment: I have solved it with the help of this youtube video [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVRWJxQR1bw&ab_channel=TheWalkingProgrammers) and the corresponding code at this Github repo [repo](https://github.com/saleh1312/python/blob/master/opencv%20-%203d%20rotation).